How to make Substring keys with String.Index for count all occurrences of all size 2 substrings
I'm not familiar with String.Index, is there a better way to make the substring keys than this:
let a = "GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA"

let keysize = 2
let size = a.count + 1 - keysize
var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

var i = 0
while i < size {
   let start_offset = a.index(seq.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
   let end = a.index(start_offset, offsetBy: keysize)     
   if let key = String( a[start_offset..<end] ) {   
      if let v = counts[key] {   
         counts[key] = v + 1  
      } else {
         counts[key] = 1 
      }
   }
   i += 1     
}

for (k,v) in counts {
   print("\(k): \(v)")   
}

Result:
CC: 5
TA: 1
TG: 3
GC: 9
CG: 7
GT: 2
GA: 3
CA: 3
AC: 2
TC: 2
AG: 3
AT: 1
TT: 2
GG: 12
AA: 1
CT: 3


Use .chunks(of: 2) from Apple's swift-algorithms https://swiftinit.org/docs/swift-algorithms/algorithms/chunking

What's not good about your current code? I think it's ok as it is.

@Alexander OP's code is doing windows(ofCount: 2), not chunks.

@Sweeper : the seq String will be 250MB

@igouy you can use sequence method to compute it lazily

Okay, so it's a performance problem. Perhaps don't use String then. Presumably there are not going to be other characters than CGAT, so just read them in as bytes. Just for the record, how fast is your current code?

There's a suggestion that seq.utf8 would allow the compiler to index efficiently?

.chunks(of:) won't work. The OP wants a string of "123456" to generate pairs of ["12", "23", "45", "56"]. .chunks(of:2) would only generate ["12", "34", "56"]

Sweeper, the performance problem is the use of a loop with for i... .index(seq.startIndex, offsetBy: i). That is going to have n-squared time performance. See my answer. For a 250MB string, that wouldn't complete before the heat-death of the universe.

@Sweeper : With 2.5MB input the program timed-out after 2 hours. With utf8 the program processed the 2.5MB file in 3.6 seconds.

You can try using this. Tested in Xcode 16.0
let seq = "GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA"
let keysize = 2
var counts: [String: Int] = [:] 
for i in seq.indices.dropLast(keysize - 1) { 
let key = String(seq[i..<seq.index(i, offsetBy: keysize)])
 counts[key, default: 0] += 1 
}


Very elegant solution. (Voted). I like the use of indices.dropLast, and counts[key, default: 0] += 1. I read about that when It was first added to the language, but haven't used it so forgot about it.

fwiw 238.01s for this version and 174.10s for utf8 version.

The official Swift Algorithms package makes short work of this, using windows(ofCount: 2):
import Algorithms

let counts = seq
    .windows(ofCount: 2)
    .reduce(into: [:]) { counts, window in
        counts[window, default: 0] += 1
    }

counts
    .sorted { $0.value > $1.value } // Optional: sort before printing
    .forEach { k, v in print("\(k): \(v)") }


Interesting. @Sweeper sort-of suggested that but sort-of didn't?

error: no such module 'Algorithms'

You need to add it as a dependency: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-package-dependencies-to-your-app  See https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms

Given the specific problem and its scale, I expect this would greatly benefit from reading the file as Data and never constructing a String. Alexander's code will work identically for Data, except for the print bit, where you'll need to turn it back into String with String(decoding: k, as: UTF8.self). In your situation you may be able to avoid making many of the Strings, which is good. Avoiding that will likely greatly improve performance, particularly if you read the file using Data(contentsOf: url, options: [.mappedIfSafe]), which can avoid loading the file into memory all at once.

@igouy Read the reaadme of the package I linked. It shows how to add it to your project. Also, if performance is an issue, Rob's suggestion to use the Data directly is great.

@Rob Napier : Seems like  swift-algorithms requires use of Swift package-manager and folder layouts and... this program happily compiles with swiftc on the command line. Yes, optimized programs wouldn't use String, but this un-optimized program should, and should still compute the result in a few minutes.

@igouy It might not be your cup of tea, but yeah, SPM is the established standard for package management for Swift. That includes defining and running test suites, which is otherwise much more of a free-for-all.

Internally, String objects can save their data in different encodings. UTF8, for example, uses variable numbers of bytes to store each glyph. As a result, fetching a glyph by index is relatively expensive. String.Index enables you to write code that traverses strings rapidly and efficiently, but indexing from the first glyph (using index(:offsetBy:)) with an index that counts to the end has O(n) time complexity for each call. Thus your code will have ≈O(n^2) (a.k.a "n-squared") time complexity. For short strings, that won't be a big problem, but if you try to apply it to longer strings its performance will get really bad.
You should try to rewrite it to use a String.Index based on the previous index. Alternately, you can convert your String to an array of Characters and index into that with integer indexes. That's fast, but takes more memory.
The approach of converting your String to an array of Character might look like this:
import Foundation

let seq = "GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA"

let array = Array(seq)
let pairs = NSCountedSet()
for index in 0..<array.count-1 {
    let pair = "\(array[index])\(array[index+1])"
    pairs.add(pair)
}
pairs.forEach { print($0, pairs.count(for: $0))}

(NSCountedSet seems like a better fit for your application than a Dictionary, although you could certainly use a Dictionary.)
I wrote some code comparing your approach to mine using an Array of Character:
import Foundation

let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let alphaArray = Array(alphabet)
var seq = ""
var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

func addPair(aPair: String) {
    if let v = counts[aPair] {
       counts[aPair] = v + 1
    } else {
       counts[aPair] = 1
    }
}

for _ in 0...100_000 {
    seq.append(alphaArray[Int.random(in:0..<alphaArray.count)] )
}
var start = Date()
let array = Array(seq)
let pairs = NSCountedSet()
for index in 0..<array.count-1 {
    let pair = "\(array[index])\(array[index+1])"
    pairs.add(pair)
}
let elapsed1 = -start.timeIntervalSinceNow
print(elapsed1)

start = Date()
let keysize = 2
let lasti = seq.count - keysize

counts = [:]

for i in 0...lasti {
    let ii = seq.index(seq.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
    let jj = seq.index(ii, offsetBy: keysize)
    
    let key = String( seq[ii..<jj] )
    pairs.add(key)
}
let elapsed2 = -start.timeIntervalSinceNow
print(elapsed2)
print("Array processing is \(elapsed2/elapsed1) times faster")

The output is
0.03937792778015137
25.516054034233093
Array processing is 647.9785878193057 times faster

So for 100_000 characters, the array based approach is almost 650x faster. For larger strings, the offset-from-the-start approach will get much, much slower. (N-squared performance goes to hell really fast for large datasets.)


You should try to rewrite it to use a String.Index based on the previous index.< Yes, I need an example that shows how to do that.


I added an answer using an array. See Kendar Sukerkar's excellent answer for code using indices.

For a string 250MB long, your solution likely would not complete in your lifetime. (n-squared time performance gets really bad for large datasets. For 250MB that would be about 68,719,476,736,000,000 operations.)

I made minor adjustments to the original program, which seem to have radically changed the performance.

Kedar Sukerkar's answer is probably the best. It should perform very well and handle any chunk size you need.

When data is empty this >> for index in 0..<array.count-1 { <<  seems to convert into a trap. It seems to convert into a 0..-1 which attempt access with index 0 and -1 instead of a loop guard which prevents access with out-of-range indexes !

Never use 0..<array.count-1. It crashes on empty inputs. An easy better replacement is just: array.indices.dropLast().

@Alexander good point.

@Alexander : As I said. People will try to use that idiom and be baffled at it's failure.

@ioguy Yep, that's why I suggested the correct alternative :)

I usually use that approach and add bounds checking to avoid the crash. array.indicies.dropLast() is much cleaner.

@Duncan C : Yeah, that was my first re-write but now there seems a risk of forgetting why it was done and removing the code, so making sure it's part-of the loop using while feels better to me.

.utf8 was more performant (with 250MB input).
let seq = "GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA"
let a = seq.utf8

let keysize = 2
let size = a.count + 1 - keysize
var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

var i = 0
while i < size {
   let start_offset = a.index(seq.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
   let end = a.index(start_offset, offsetBy: keysize)     
   if let key = String( a[start_offset..<end] ) {   
      if let v = counts[key] {   
         counts[key] = v + 1  
      } else {
         counts[key] = 1 
      }
   }
   i += 1     
}

I had to adjust some method parameters to be String.UTF8View

Using utf8 will only work for characters that are in the extended ASCII character set. If you use characters that take more than one byte in UTF8 your code will get completely confused. (accented characters, letters from the Greek or other non-Roman alphabets, etc. Try "AÄBÇñüÉÈ" as a string, just as an example.

converting your string to utf16 would yield good results for a much larger group of characters. (Thinks like Kanji characters that require more than 16 bits would still confuse it.

https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms/iupac.html

@igouy I'm surprised there's much difference in performance here. IIRC String has an optimization for ascii-only strings like this one, which make indexing much faster than the general unicode case. Are you sure you're testing this with an optimized (release) build?

Also, if that utf8 trick did really help improve performance, you can apply it really easily to my answer. You just need to add in the .utf8 and .map { String($0)! } stages, like so: seq.utf8.windows(ofCount: 2).map { String($0)! }.reduce(into: [:]) { counts, window in counts[window, default: 0] += 1 }.

@Alexander : You haven't given the swiftc command line which you call "an optimized (release) build" ?

Nope, I assumed you could look into that. The exact steps depend on which platform you’re working on. Is this a Swift package, or an Xcode project?

This is linux. -Ounchecked "Compile with optimizations and remove runtime safety checks" -wmo

@igouy did that help? How much perf improvement was there? And how did using the UTF8View  compare with just using the string directly?

Those are the compiler options I have used -- so no change.

@igouy I don't get notified unless you mention my username. So how did the windows(ofCount:) solution compare, performance wise? I expect it to be the same as this hand written alternative

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Alexander : seems like you'll only trust your own measurements, so please make some :-)

What gave you that impression? I literally just asked for your measurements, because i’m curious of the results.
